# remove padding from ButtonTheme

Tags: flutter

While DropdownMenuItem is wider than DropdownButton, I found the solution is wrapped with ButtonTheme, but then there always a empty space in front of text, plz check screenshot that I dont know how to remove. So my purpose is simple, make DropdownMenuItem has same width as DropdownButton meanwhile text is left aligned, plz help me.... thank you a lot!

```
        ButtonTheme(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0), // doesnt work here
          alignedDropdown: true,
          minWidth: 0,
          materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
          height: 0,
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            style: mainTextStyle(textColor: AppColors.mainFontColor),
            value: selectedGender,
            focusNode: _genderFocusNode,
            focusColor: Colors.redAccent,
            hint: Text(
              'Select your gender',
              style:
                  hintTextStyle(textColor: AppColors.hintFontColor),
            ),
            underline: Container(
              height: 1,
              color: AppColors.hintFontColor,
            ),
            isExpanded: true,
            items: genderItems.map((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) => setState(()=>selectedGender = value),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

I dont why there is always a spacing on the left side... has anyone any idea?
[image]

Comment: Hi, any update about your issue? plz share if you found the solution. tq